# Torsion in cohomology

Tags: cohomology, chain-complexes, torsion

Suppose to have a short exact sequence of chain complexes of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules:
$$0\to A^\bullet\to B^\bullet\to C^\bullet\to 0$$
such that $A^k,B^k,C^k$ are non zero for $k=0,1,2$.
Moreover, suppose that $H^j(C^\bullet)$ is torsion free and non-zero, for all $j=0,1,2$. Is it true that if $H^2(A^\bullet)$ is torsion free, then also $H^2(B^\bullet)$ is torsion free? What about the converse?

Comment: Of course not, take $A = Z$ (in degree 0), $B = Z \stackrel{2}\to Z$ (in degrees $-1$ and 0), $C = Z$ (in degree $-1$).

Comment: you are right, I forgot a couple of assumptions.

Comment: Add to $A$ and $C$ arbitrary acyclic complexes and to $B$ their direct sum.

Comment: I am thinking of chain complexes with $A^k=0$, for $k<0$. Does this make any difference?

Comment: @user53075 You can shift Sasha's example up so that $A$ is concentrated in degree 2, $B$ is concentrated in degrees $1$ and $2$, and $C$ is concentrated in degree $1$.

Comment: Ok, but if I understand correctly, this example does not satisfy that $H^i(C)$ is non zero for all $i$.